# Postgres Join Query for a table referencing itself

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a table badges with the following schemas

```
create table badges (
 id, serial primary key,
 title, text not null,
 next_badge_id: int references badges,
 .
 .
)
```

Given table as:

```
id |      title       | next_badge_id
----+------------------+---------------
  1 | Bronze Partner   |             2
  2 | Silver partner   |             3
  3 | Gold partner     |             4
  4 | Diamond partner  |             5
  5 | Platinum partner |
```

How do I write a query to return this:

```
id |      title       | next_badge
----+------------------+---------------
  1 | Bronze Partner   | Silver partner
  2 | Silver partner   | Gold partner
  3 | Gold partner     | Diamond partner 
  4 | Diamond partner  | Platinum partner
  5 | Platinum partner |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left join` query

Sample data and query structure: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=39806caf2caf8e3e33b9837044197029)

```sql
select
  b1.id,
  b1.title,
  b2.title as next_badge
from
  badges b1
  left join badges b2 on b1.next_badge_id = b2.id
```

Comment: Yeah, what I have been doing is ..on b1.id = b2.next_badge_id. My bad. Thanks